# Receiving Laravel CSRF token mismatch error in spite of X-XSRF-Token header being sent appropriately

Tags: angular, laravel, csrf

Working with an Angular front end with a Laravel back end, and I can't seem to get past the CSRF step with Sanctum.

The weird thing is that I'm hitting the /sanctum/csrf-cookie page and getting the XSRF-Token cookie back (image 1), and when I hit my /auth route in Laravel the X-XSRF-TOKEN header seems to be set appropriately (image 2), but it's still giving me the CSRF token mismatch error.

[image: XSRF-Token cookie returned]

[image: X-XSRF-Token header sent]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I just needed to uncomment the EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful line from the api middleware group in my Kernel.php.